# How to import multiple Frida JS files/functions into the runtime CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frida

I'm putting together a Frida test bench for co-workers, and am unfamiliar with JavaScript and Node.JS. I would like to create a single JS file that imports several other JS files, each with several functions. But when I use frida-compile against some Node.JS code that imports other functions, the REPL interpreter is not pulling the functions/variables into scope. So, for example:

I have a flat directory consisting of 3 JavaScript files:

in1.js:

```
'use strict';
var a = 'test';
function b() { console.log("function b"); };
```

in2.js:

```
'use strict';
var c = 'test2';
var d = function () { console.log("function d"); };
```

in3.js:

```
'use strict';
require('./in1.js');
require('./in2.js');
```

Then I run frida-compile, on Windows 10 + Python 3.6 + Node.JS 9.5:

```
frida-compile in3.js -o out.js
```

Which results in the following output:

```
(function(){function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s}return e})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var a = 'test';
function b() {
  console.log("function b");
};

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var c = 'test2';
var d = function () {
  console.log("function d");
};

},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

require('./in1.js');
require('./in2.js');

},{"./in1.js":1,"./in2.js":2}]},{},[3])
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIi4uLy4uLy4uL25vZGVfbW9kdWxlcy9icm93c2VyLXBhY2svX3ByZWx1ZGUuanMiLCJpbjEuanMiLCJpbjIuanMiLCJpbjMuanMiXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IkFBQUE7QUNBQTs7QUFDQSxJQUFJLElBQUksTUFBUjtBQUNBLElBQUksSUFBSSxZQUFZO0FBQUUsVUFBUSxHQUFSLENBQVksWUFBWjtBQUE0QixDQUFsRDs7O0FDRkE7O0FBQ0EsSUFBSSxJQUFJLE9BQVI7QUFDQSxJQUFJLElBQUksWUFBWTtBQUFFLFVBQVEsR0FBUixDQUFZLFlBQVo7QUFBNEIsQ0FBbEQ7OztBQ0ZBOztBQUNBLFFBQVEsVUFBUjtBQUNBLFFBQVEsVUFBUiIsImZpbGUiOiJnZW5lcmF0ZWQuanMiLCJzb3VyY2VSb290IjoiIn0=
```

Lastly, when I try importing it into the Frida CLI, using the OWASP iGoat project as an example, I cannot access any of those functions:

```
    frida -R -f com.swaroop.iGoat -l out.js
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 10.6.52 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at http://www.frida.re/docs/home/
Spawned `com.swaroop.iGoat`. Use %resume to let the main thread start executing!
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> %resume
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> a
ReferenceError: identifier 'a' undefined
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> b
ReferenceError: identifier 'b' undefined
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> c
ReferenceError: identifier 'c' undefined
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> d
ReferenceError: identifier 'd' undefined
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> module
ReferenceError: identifier 'module' undefined
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> require
ReferenceError: identifier 'require' undefined
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]-> exports
ReferenceError: identifier 'exports' undefined
[Remote::com.swaroop.iGoat]->
```

What am I missing... How do I access a,b,c, and d within the Frida CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can directly access any of the variables from a script.

Reading the Frida sources (specifically bindings/gumjs/runtime/core.js from the frida-gum repo), they add properties to the variable `global`, which seems to behave as the global object (an object that acts as a store for all global variables, like `window` in the browser) for the JS executed in the REPL.

And indeed, this kind of code in the script:

```
global.test = "success";
```

Defines a new variable in the REPL:

```
[iPhone::Foo]-> test
"success"
```

(Also thanks for introducing me to `frida-compile`, it's making my life a lot easier right now.)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a direct answer, you need to "export" them with the global variable.
So to call your function `d()` you should add this line at the end of the script:

`global.d = d;`

Then you can call the function on your cli just by calling:

`d()`

or with params

`d("parameter")`